# Google data studio : Error in formula for custom fields with REGEXP_MATCH

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm currently playing with Google Data Studio and I'm having an error that I can't get rid of.

I'm trying to create a custom field that will store some values depending on the result of my regex, see below the code :
[image]

GDS is not accepting this formula as I'm getting the error : `Invalid Formula`.

The documentation about `REGEXP_MATCH` is also saying that it returns **true** or **false** but when I just get the return of the regex `'.'` (looking for any character), I do not get any of these values. Instead it shows me `{$theCharacterFound}` ex : `{A}`.

Hope someone will be able to tell me what I am doing wrong !

**EDIT** : I found out in this [topic](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Data-Studio/CASE-with-REGEXP-MATCH-gives-quot-Invalid-formula-quot/m-p/1846343#) that it is apparently **a problem with the postgreSQL connector** (that I'm using) so we can only hope that Google will fix it...

Comment: Your question does make complete sense to me.  The `CASE` expression can _only_ return either `'Good'`, `'Bad'`, or `NULL`, and nothing else.  What values are being returned from your `CASE` expression?

Comment: No values are returned from the `CASE` because Google Data Studio does not accept my formula, that is the problem ...

Comment: Your CASE statement / REGEXP_MATCH looks fine to me. I'd check your data and see if you can see anything that might cause issues

Comment: My data seems to be ok as I can replace my `CASE` statement by a simple `REGEXP_MATCH(satisfaction_rating_score, 'on')` (But it is not what I want ) it returns `{on}` for lines that contains it.

Comment: I start to think that it is a issue from GDS, but it seems too big

Comment: What do you get on the lines that don't match? (referring to the REGEXP_MATCH(satisfaction_rating_score, 'on'))

Comment: I've tried an equivalent CASE statement on my own data (same regex) and get the expected results. When you say you get "{on}" is that in a re2 test or have you tried putting your data into a table on Data Studio to test the results?

Comment: I tried to put the custom field into a table ! I don't understand why my CASE statement is not accepted so ...

Comment: I also tried to just copy and past code from the doc here : https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476?hl=fr and changed the field "pays" by my Text field and I still get the same error...

Comment: In that case I can only conclude it's something to do with your data although I'm not sure what. Can you somehow look for special characters or something?

Comment: Ok so instead of my usual text field, i used another text field containing only 3 possible values : "question", "task" or "null", and I still get the error ...

Comment: I can confirm that it is a problem with my data (Postgresql connector) as I have been able to make the Case statement worked with another set of data from google sheet. But I still can't see what is wrong with my data, the connector haha ?

Comment: I can't help you with that but at least you're one step closer!

Comment: Yes thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an `r` before the regex literal:

```
CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(my_field_text, r'\bWord1\b') THEN 'True'
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(my_field_text, r'\bWord2\b') THEN 'False'
    ELSE NULL
END
```

Note also that I placed word boundaries around your search term words.  This will prevent `Word1` from matching a substring in a large string, e.g. `AWord1s`, which you might not want to count as a match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my regex expression is not the problem ;)
If your prefer, I could be looking for any character in my text like '.'

Comment: I think there _is_ a problem with your regex, but in any case, post your entire query, which I think is where the actual problem is.  Are you using standard BigQuery?

Comment: I edited my question with the formula I want to use, I don't know standard BigQuery so I can't tell you, I just guess I am not dealing with SQL.